# Sqlite, replace backslash with slash

Tags: sql, sqlite, replace, special-characters

I have to replace a the backslash with the slash with a query in sqlite:

```
update track_locations set location = replace(location, '\', '/');
```

How i can replace this special char?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run the code you provided from the console and it is working fine. So you might be not escaping it properly in whatever programming language you're using.

Comment: Yes, it works. I was using the client manager SQLiteMan in Ubuntu, but tring with SQLite Data Browser it works! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The escape charater is \ so placing it front of another character will replace it.  In your case you want

```
update track_locations set location = replace(location, '\\', '/');
```

Another example to help clarify is if you wanted to escape an apostrophe it would '\''